# Ruby on consoles emulators

Tags: ruby, windows

I am unable to use Ruby on consoles emulators, ConEmu, PowerCmd,
Ruby programs execute perfect on windows default CMD, (and I hate it)
I tried uninstalling Ruby and install it again but it doesn't work. once
the program try to get in put, (when there is no input program execute
fine) here is the error message I am getting on ConEmu:

```
C:\Users\1234> "D:\Desktopbackup\Ruby lessons\1102divdbyZero.rb"
Enter numerator: D:/Desktopbackup/Ruby lessons/1102divdbyZero.rb:2:
[BUG] Segmentation
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]

-- Control frame information
-----------------------------------------------
c:0004 p:---- s:0012 e:000011 CFUNC  :gets
c:0003 p:---- s:0010 e:000009 CFUNC  :gets
c:0002 p:0013 s:0007 E:002638 EVAL   D:/Desktopbackup/Ruby
lessons/1102divdbyZero.rb:2
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:002024 TOP    [FINISH]

D:/Desktopbackup/Ruby lessons/1102divdbyZero.rb:2:in `<main>'
D:/Desktopbackup/Ruby lessons/1102divdbyZero.rb:2:in `gets'
D:/Desktopbackup/Ruby lessons/1102divdbyZero.rb:2:in `gets'

-- C level backtrace information
-------------------------------------------
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll(ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15) [0x7769F8D1]
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll(WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x43)
[0x766C1194]
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll(WaitForSingleObject+0x12) [0x766C1148]
C:\Ruby21\bin\msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0xa7) [0x6D394A17]
C:\Ruby21\bin\msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_name_err_mesg_new+0x69f)
[0x6D248F7F]
C:\Ruby21\bin\msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_bug+0x2e) [0x6D249D5E]
C:\Ruby21\bin\msvcrt-ruby210.dll(rb_check_safe_str+0x34b) [0x6D31486B]
 [0x00401866]
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll(RtlKnownExceptionFilter+0xb7) [0x776F74FF]

-- Other runtime information
-----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: D:/Desktopbackup/Ruby lessons/1102divdbyZero.rb

* Loaded features:



 0 enumerator.so
    1 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32/enc/encdb.so
    2 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    3 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so
    4 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32/rbconfig.rb
    5 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    6 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    7 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    8 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    9 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/version.rb
   10 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   11 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   12 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   13 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   14 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
   15 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   16 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   17 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
   18 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   19 thread.rb
   20 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32/thread.so
   21 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb
   22 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   23 C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension
libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

and on other console PowerCmd once it's get the input it gets blank.
I have been trying to solve this problem for couple of days in vain.

Edit: I reported the bug and this is the reply I got:

This was fixed in the code: bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/… Which will be part of next release. I recommend you use cmd.exe until an updated version is ship with the fix.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: you mean to say that the original program? this error appears when ever a program asks for input, with gets command, as soon as I try to input (by pressing any key)

Comment: "Ask for input" is not very specific. The error shows `gets`, but are you using `STDIN.gets`? Or `Kernel.gets`? Or something other `gets` function? I *think* it's `STDIN.gets`, but I don't *know* that for sure... In any case, it may very well be a bug in Ruby. you probably want to follow the link in the error message (http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html) and check if a bugreport already exists, and report one if it doesn't.

Comment: I reported the bug and this is the reply I got:

This was fixed in the code:

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/48585

Which will be part of next release.

I recommend you use cmd.exe until an updated version is ship with the fix.